# WebFlux/Reactive Spring RabbitmMq Message is acknowledged even the save failed

Tags: spring-rabbit

I've started working recently with spring webflux and Rabbitmq along with cassandra reactive repository. What I've noticed is that the message is acknowledged even saving in cassandra didn't succued for some element. I propagete exception thrown during saving but even though the message is take down from queue. I'm wondering what I should do to let Rabbitmq know that this message should be consider as failed (I want to reject message to send it to dead letter queue )

```
@RabbitListener(queues = Constants.SOME_QUEUE, returnExceptions = "true")
public void receiveMessage(final List<ItemList> itemList) {
    log.info("Received message from queue: {}", Constants.SOME_QUEUE);
    itemService.saveAll(itemList)
            .subscribe(
                    item-> log.info("Saving item with {}", item.getId()),
                    error -> {
                        log.error("Error during saving item", error);
                        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(error.getMessage());
                    },
                    () -> log.info(Constants.SOME_QUEUE+
                            " queue - {} items saved", itemList.size())
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactive is non-blocking; the message will be acked as soon as the listener thread returns to the container. You need to somehow block the listener thread (e.g. with a `Future<?>`) and wake it up when the cassandra operation completes, exiting normally if successful, or throwing an exception on failure so the message will be redelivered.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the answer. As far as I know there is no possiblity to block thread when using webflux and netty. I found a workaround for this problem and I'm sending acknowledgment and rejection manually to rabbitmq

Comment: That is correct, but the listener thread itself is not reactive; you are bridging from the non-reactive world to the reactive world. It's ok to block the listener thread after the `.subscribe()` returns; then wake it up with the result. Manual acks will solve the success case, but it won't solve the failure case, in which case you need the listener thread to throw an exception so the message will be redelivered (or sent to a DLQ if so configured).

Comment: If any exception occurs I'm sending manually rejection message so failure path is also covered. I will try to learn more about what have you written and I'll check if I'm able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by sending explicitly acknowledge/reject message to rabbitmq. It caused that I was forced to wrote a little more code but now at least it works and I have full controll what's happening.